# Warning:"NAs introduced by coercion" in MICE with unique ID

Tags: r, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am having a problem using MICE, where it generates the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In var(data[, j], na.rm = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

This seems to be related to the presence of a unique alphanumeric ID variable in the data. For example:

```
require(mice)

imp <- mice(nhanes,maxit=0)
# no problem

nhanes$id <- 1:25
imp <- mice(nhanes,exclude="id",maxit=0)
# no problem

nhanes$id <- LETTERS[1:25]
imp <- mice(nhanes,exclude="id",maxit=0)
```

The latter generates the warning:

```
In var(data[, j], na.rm = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The predictor matrix is

> imp$pred

```
    age bmi hyp chl id
age   0   0   0   0  0
bmi   1   0   1   1  0
hyp   1   1   0   1  0
chl   1   1   1   0  0
id    0   0   0   0  0
```

Note that here `id` is not used to impute anything. So it seems strange that a warning would be generated at all, in this simple case. Even this generates the same warning:

```
pred <- imp$pred

imp <- mice(
  data=nhanes,
  m = 5,  
  maxit=5,
  imputationMethod = c(
    "norm",  # age
    "norm",  # bmi
    "norm",  # hyp
    "norm",  # chl
    "")    ,  # id
  predictorMatrix = pred
)
```

where id is not specified to be imputed or to be used for imputation in the predictor matrix, and the imputation method is ""

So my questions are:

> 1. Why is this warning generated ?
> 2. How can I prevent this warning, without removing the ID variable from the data. Of course I don't use the ID variable for imputing other variables - it's just a bit inconvenient to remove it.
> 3. If it can't be prevented, can I safely ignore the warning and use the predictor matrix for imputing my data (after setting the id column to zeros) ?

Comment: Have you contacted the package maintainer yet? In my experience, he is very open to suggestions (especially if you provide him with a reproducible example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. This is subtle `R` behavior. If we do

```
nhanes$id <- LETTERS[1:25]
```

the matrix `nhanes` gets transformed into a `data.frame`, but it does not convert `id` into a `factor`, as one might expect, and leaves it character (`mice` does not handle character variables). I did not know that this was possible, but it may make sense in particular applications.

On the other hand, using the preferred syntax

```
nhanes <- data.frame(nhanes, id = LETTERS[1:25])
```

will also convert `nhanes` into a `data.frame` and converts `id` into `factor`, which eliminates the warning.

Comment: Thanks Stef. My data has 700,000 unique obs so I'm not sure it's a good idea to have a factor variable with this many levels. At the moment I am removing the variable prior to imputation then adding it back with `cbind.mids` afterwards. I'd prefer not to do this if possible - is it safe to ignore the warning ? Also, after `cbind.mids`, is there an easy way to rename the variable, since it seems to always be named `y` ?

Comment: Ah yes, making a factor of 700,000 unique values is a recipe for disaster. It is safe to ignore the warning, but I will adapt the code in the next release to prevent it. Current behavior is that character variables are simply copied, and not imputed. This seems appropriate in your case.